# Does std::bitset<64> work on 32 bit machines for uint64_t?

Tags: c++

The output of code below on a 32 bit Linux (RHEL6) machine with Intel compiler with enabled -std=c++11 is like below - why?

```
uint64_t a = UINT64_MAX;
std::cout << std::bitset<64>(a) << std::endl;
```

Output on 32 bit machine:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111
```

Output on 64 bit machine:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Comment: Is the output different on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: Because `std::bitset` is broken before C++11 - has a constructor accepting `unsigned long` which is 32-bit type on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: What types are allowed for the constructor of `std::bitset`?

Comment: This is NOT on Windows - it is using Intel compiler on 32 bit Linux with -std=c++11

Comment: can you please provide your command for compilation? also what compiler do you use? what OS?

Comment: RHEL6 was released in 2010. Looks like C++ runtime you are using doesn't fully support C++11 (even if your compiler does). You need a newer runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does std::bitset<64> work on 32 bit machines for uint64_t?

Yes, since C++11.

Prior to C++11, the constructor accepted a `unsigned long` which is only guaranteed to be 32 bits or larger. When the size of the bitset exceeds the number of bits in `long` (prior to C++11) or `long long` (since C++11), the overflowing bits are initialised to 0.

The larger bitsets can be used, but the high bits cannot be initialised with this constructor nor observed with `to_ulong`.

Comment: @pmoubed Then that language implementation does not conform to C++11 standard.

Comment: icpc (ICC) 15.0.3 20150407 - https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler.html

Comment: @pmoubed According to that documentation `Linux: Note that language features available can depend on gcc* version installed` You should check whether your standard library supports C++11.